# How to send File via Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I need to send txt File using TelegramBot API .

I already tried https://api.telegram.org/botMYT0KEN/sendDocument?chat_id=569502265&document=/Users/users/Desktop/file.txt

and have issue :

> {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong remote
>   file id specified: Wrong string length”}

Answer (score 13):

To complete Donny's answer, I would like to add an example of sending `.txt` file as a document.

Looks like you're using OS X as an operating system, which has `curl` utility preinstalled.

Open terminal and make a request like this:

```sh
curl -v -F "chat_id=569502265" -F document=@/Users/users/Desktop/file.txt https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendDocument
```

Comment: I want to add that if the chat is a public one i.e. "@mychannel" it will not work unless we change the -F for --form-string for specifying the chat_id. Like this: curl -v --form-string "chat_id=@mychannel" -F document=@/Users/$USER/Desktop/file.txt api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendDocument

Answer (score 6):

From Telegram official documentation

> Sending files There are three ways to send files (photos, stickers, audio, media, etc.):
>
> If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you
>   don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field,
>   simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There
>   are no limits for files sent this way. Provide Telegram with an HTTP
>   URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file.
>   5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
>   Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files
>   are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for
>   other files. Sending by file_id
>
> It is not possible to change the file type when resending by file_id.
>   I.e. a video can't be sent as a photo, a photo can't be sent as a
>   document, etc. It is not possible to resend thumbnails. Resending a
>   photo by file_id will send all of its sizes. file_id is unique for
>   each individual bot and can't be transferred from one bot to another.
>   Sending by URL
>
> When sending by URL the target file must have the correct MIME type
>   (e.g., audio/mpeg for sendAudio, etc.). In sendDocument, sending by
>   URL will currently only work for gif, pdf and zip files. To use
>   sendVoice, the file must have the type audio/ogg and be no more than
>   1MB in size. 1–20MB voice notes will be sent as files. Other
>   configurations may work but we can't guarantee that they will.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

This is what you need from your question:

> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files
>   are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for
>   other files

Comment: This doesn't help, the documentation doesn't shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the POST method instead GET. For example, I use https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

```
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botId.'/sendDocument';
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->post($url, [
    "chat_id" => $chatId,
    "document" => new \CURLFile($file_path)
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need interacting with a bot api using Bash and curl, there is a good one we use

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

### for debugging
if [[ ${debug:-false} == 'true' ]]; then
    set -x
fi

declare -r usage="[debug=true] ${0%.sh} <file-name> [your-message-as-caption]"
if (( ${#} == 0 )); then
    echo $usage
    exit 0
fi

### file name and user caption
declare -r user_file=${1:? error ... user_file ?}
declare -r user_caption="${2:-here is your file <b>$user_file</b>}"

if ! [[ -f $user_file ]]; then
    echo "$user_file not found or is not a regular file"
    exit 1;
fi

declare -r bot_token=YOUR_TOKEN
declare -r bot_chat_id=YOUR_CHAT_ID
declare -r bot_log_file=${0%.sh}.log

### sendDocument -- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument
curl -sL  \
    -o $bot_log_file \
    -F document=@"$user_file" \
    -F chat_id="$bot_chat_id" \
    -F parse_mode="HTML" \
    -F caption="$user_caption" \
    -X POST \
    https://api.telegram.org/bot$bot_token/sendDocument

### validate the result
declare -r send_doc_result=$(jq '.ok' < $bot_log_file)
if [[ $send_doc_result == 'true' ]]; then
    echo "[Y] done"
else
    declare -r error_description=$(jq '.description' < $bot_log_file)
    echo "[X] error: $error_description"
    exit 1
fi
```

you should update these two lines

```bash
declare -r bot_token=YOUR_TOKEN
declare -r bot_chat_id=YOUR_CHAT_ID
```

Then you can save the script and run it.

- a **file name** is required
- but **caption** and **debug** mode are optional
- Bash 4.4+ is needed
- jq command is needed