# Post a file to bot using sendDocument method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, bots, telegram

I am trying to send a html document to a bot using `requests` in python.

```py
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot******/sendDocument'
response = requests.post( url = url, 
                          data = { 'chat_id' : chat_id, 
                                   'document': open('/home/user/page.html', 'rb'),
                          }
           )
```

I get `<Response [400]>`. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119656/4873716) and able to post html document to the bot using `curl` but not using `requests`.

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you send local document using telegram bot API

```py
import requests

BOT_TOKEN = " ... "
CHAT_ID = " ... "

url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendDocument"


response = requests.post(url=url,
                         data={
                             'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
                             'document': 'attach://file',
                         },
                         files={
                             'file': open('./page.html', 'rb'),
                         }
                      )

print(response.json())
```

Comment: glad to help. consider [up-voting/accepting the answer if you found it useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I already did that. It doesnt show up there because my “reputation” is less than 15 :)

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue with C++ and based my solution on your answer.