# How can download images in Web App Telegram?

Tags: javascript

I try to add files in web app with code:

```
import { useEffect} from 'react';

const tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    tg.ready();
  }, [])

  const submitForm = ()=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit!");
    
  }
  return (
    <>
      <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <input type="file" multiple />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

This works everywhere on IOS  except telegram on Android OS.
It works in browser Android too.

But in Telegram on Android I can't select multiple files.
The input:file has an error "file not found".
This only works for selecting one file

Why don't work in telegram web app in Android?

Comment: what do you mean telegram wen app android ? can you elaborate your question and provide more code ?

Comment: I mean about https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#implementing-mini-apps. This is app in telegram-bot. I use React and 
there are no differences from a regular application, except that it needs to be connected to a bot

Comment: again! you still need to share more of your code so we can see where is the issue coming from, we can't go look in documentation for you to show you how to do it, you need to share more of your code in order for this community to help you resolve the issue you are facing.

Comment: and maybe look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470047/how-to-send-file-via-telegram-bot

Comment: Thanks. I can't even select files in Telegram-bot on Android. On IOS works

Comment: you have a typo here `const submitForm = ()=> {
    e.prevendDefault();
    console.log("submit!");
    
  }` should be `const submitForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Corrected typo
  console.log("submit!");
}`

Comment: <input type="file" onChange={handle change in file here} />

Comment: Thank you. I tried it in different ways and through useForm. But it’s the input multiple that doesn’t work.